# Unable to use external monitor's full resolution using Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, hdmi, resolution

I recently bought a new 2019 MacBook Pro. It working as expected. I use my HP 22Es for majority of my work. Very unfortunately, my MBP is unable to detect the 1920x1080 resolution of external display.

I did some research and came to know about **SwitchResX** and some information about **EDID** data. I tried everything I could. But still there are limitations like *Disabling the System Integrity protection* etc!!

I wonder if some has a easy to read guide or a blog post! It would be great help.

My configuration is like below:

1. Mac - MacBook Pro 2019, 13 Inch, TouchBar
2. OS - MacOS Mojave
3. External Display - HP 22ES
4. Display Adapter - Apple's USB Thunderbolt to HDMI converter
5. I use Belkin's HDMI to HDMI converter

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). As for your question, can you please [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/367186/edit) your post to clarify what you mean by *"my MBP is unable to detect the 1920x1080 resolution of external display"*?

Comment: It's just not clear from your post whether you're saying that everything works fine except when trying to use that display resolution, or whether the HP display doesn't work at all with your new MBP? Also, telling us *I tried everything I could* doesn't really tell us anything, so can you also clarify what you've actually tried?

Comment: 1. Yes everything works except display resolution

Comment: Can you tell us, or can you clarify, why you're using an HDMI to HDMI converter? I think that information could prove useful.

Comment: The macbook pro comes with 2 Thunderbolt ports only. Hence I used, Apple's USB Thunderbolt to HDMI converter (https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MUF82AM/A/usb-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter?fnode=8b)

Comment: You're not sharing what resolution the laptop DOES think the display supports.

Comment: Hi, 
My MacBook currently supporting, 1600x900, 1344x1008, 1344x756, 1280x960, 1024x576, 800x600, 720x576, 640x480, 1080p, 720p, 480p

And my Monitor (LG 22es) optimum resolution is 1920x1080

Answer (score 2):

Dude, i can tell you from personal experience; after buying four different usb-c hdmi adapters that the ONLY adapter that enabled me to utilize my external monitor full resolution + high refresh rate without having to hack internal /System/Library code or messing with SwitchResX/other b.s. GUI garbage;
is the belkin usb-c to hdmi adapter (the white version, do not use the old-black version -- its got terrible refresh rates). I also have apple's usb-c dongle (hdmi,usb-c,usb-a)[but it's utter garbage...] (didnt work); neither did the belkin black; nor did some other 'KANEX'-brand crap that i stumbled upon while cruising down a local shopping-mall. MBP 15" latest model i9's and what not (all the bells and whistles...); external monitor is an LG-4K 27" (supports real high res).
hope it helps

https://www.belkin.com/uk/p/P-F2CU038bt/
This one doesn't give you refresh rates higher then 30Hz(despite what it says on the website)

this one does : 
https://www.apple.com/uk/shop/product/HKQ22ZM/A/belkin-usb-c-to-hdmi-adapter

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
It is interesting that Apple sells that Garbage dongle without telling all of this :(